# Inserting objects into vector using lower_bound with compare struct

Tags: c++, vector, insert, constants, lower-bound

I have this class:

```
class Mail {
  public:
    Mail(const string & msg) : msg(msg) {}

    const string msg;
};
```

And this structure, which compares two Mail objects:

```
struct Compare {
  bool operator()(const Mail & mail, Mail const & mail2) const {
    return mail.msg < mail2.msg;
  }
};
```

I want to have a vector with Mail objects sorted by their message `const string msg`. However, when I try to insert new object into vector using [`lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), I get many errors, including:

> passing ‘const string as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers.

```
int main() {
  vector <Mail> mails;

  Mail mail2("1");
  mails.push_back(mail2);

  const string msg = "2";
  Mail mail(msg);
  auto low = lower_bound(mails.begin(), mails.end(), mail, Compare());

  // mails.push_back(mail);   // OK
  mails.insert(low, mail); // passing ‘const string as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers

  return 0;
}
```

I dont yet understand `const` usage much and can't figure out, which `const` is wrong.
I am sorry, if this has already been asked, but I haven't found an answer to this problem yet.

Comment: are you sure you want `string msg` to be `const`? It means that it can't be changed after initialization and that is what prevents you from inserting it.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I understand the problem now. However, I cannot change `class Mail` including `const string msg`. I changed vector to vector of pointers  `vector<CMail*>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors in C++ can sometimes be hard to diagnose. My tip is to always start at the top and resolve that one first. In this case, there's [a long list of them](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b242cb9276d4b31d), but they're all really about the same thing -- the assignment operator for `Mail` cannot be generated.

Think of it this way, the compiler is being helpful and is trying to generate (and inside `lower_bound()`, use) this function:

```
Mail& operator=( const& Mail mail ) 
{ 
    msg = mail.msg; 
    return *this;
}
```

But it can't because that assignment in the body is invalid due to `msg` being `const`. You can't really write it yourself either since you also can't assign to a `const` variable.

Usually you don't need member variables to be `const` because they become `const` if the instance of the class is itself `const`:

```cpp
const auto mail1 = Mail{"1"};
auto       mail2 = Mail{"2"};

mail1.msg = "3"; // FAIL! msg is const since mail1 is const
mail2.msg = "4"; // Ok! msg is not const
```

If you do need a `const` member, you can't use assignment operators with the class. Them's the breaks.

Remove that `const` and all works:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Mail {
  public:
    Mail(const string & msg) : msg(msg) {}

    string msg; //////////////////////////////// Not const!
};

struct Compare {
  bool operator()(const Mail & mail, Mail const & mail2) const {
    return mail.msg < mail2.msg;
  }
};

int main() {
  vector <Mail> mails;

  Mail mail2("1");
  mails.push_back(mail2);

  const string msg = "2";
  Mail mail(msg);
  auto low = lower_bound(mails.begin(), mails.end(), mail, Compare());

  // mails.push_back(mail);   // OK
  mails.insert(low, mail); // OK!

  return 0;
}
```

See it run live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5761df86c017b2a0)</kbd>.

**Footnotes**:

- You could use a lambda for the comaparator to avoid some boilerplate around the class `Compare`:

```cpp
const auto low = lower_bound( begin(mails), end(mails), mail, 
                              []( const auto& mail1, const auto& mail2 ) 
                              { return mail1.msg < mail2.msg; } );
```

- You can use [`vector::emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to construct items in place, avoiding a copy. The following blocks do the same thing in effect, but the second is more efficient:

```cpp
const auto mail = Mail{"2"};
mails.push_back( mail2 ); // Copies

mails.emplace_back("2"); // Creates it right in the vector
```

- Consider using [`vector::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) if you know how many items you'll put in your vector.

Answer (score 0):

The problems here pertain to the deleted copy assignment operator and the deleted move assignment operator because of the `const string msg;` member in the `Mail` class:

> **[Deleted implicitly-declared copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment)**
>
> A defaulted copy assignment operator for class `T` **is defined as deleted** if any of the following is true:
>
> - `T` has a non-static data member of non-class type (or array thereof) that is `const`;
>
> **[Deleted implicitly-declared move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment)**
>
> The implicitly-declared or defaulted move assignment operator for class `T` **is defined as deleted** if any of the following is true:
>
> - T has a non-static data member that is `const`;